# Can I connect my Mid 2011 Mac to a second monitor?

Tags: display, imac

How can I connect my mid 2011 iMac to a second monitor to extend my screen? The monitor is an HP L1950. The ports my mac has can be seen here:

[image: Mac Ports]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iMac has a [Thunderbolt 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)#Thunderbolt_2) connector which also acts as a [Mini DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort). 
Since your [Monitor](https://support.hp.com/nz-en/document/c01154709) supports (15-Pin D-Sub) VGA or DVI-D you either need a Mini-DisplayPort to VGA or to DVI-D cable. I would recommend getting a DVI-D (e.g from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FX50ZW4), your local store might have one of the mentioned options as well), since it is the [newer and slightly better](https://store.hp.com/us/en/tech-takes/top-advantages-dvi-vs-vga-for-computer-monitors) standard, though VGA is (for **old**) equipment more common.

In general though, this is old Hardware and HDMI is more or less standard now.